# Eclipse consuming around 85% of CPU and 3 GB RAM : very slow performance

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, performance

I'm using Eclipse 4.5.0 on my 16 GB RAM mac. I'm getting horrible performance. When I checked the memory usage and CPU utilization, they are around 3 GB and 85% respectively consumed by eclipse.

[image]

[image]

I tried disabling the spell check in eclipse as suggested in few answers but it didn't help me. Can someone please help?

Comment: How long is your code? 100,000 lines? How many source files?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, what's installed in that copy of Eclipse, and the hardware you're on, this could be perfectly normal. Can you at least retry this with 4.6.2, the **current release**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had large number of open projects in my workspace.Everytime I made any change to a project, the entire workspace(all open projects) used to get build and that was consuming lot of memory and CPU.

I turned off the **build automatically** (Project->Build Automatically) and the memory usage and the CPU utilization both looks good now.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse, 85% is highly over normal CPU consumption, under my experience. If that situation lasts too long, may be caused by a memory issue when having opened a hugh amount of source files. Try to increase the **max heap memory** in `eclipse.ini` (Having 16Gb, you seem to have a good margin still).